# Add Dynamics GP namespaces Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I need to add the following namespaces

```
• Microsoft.Dynamics.Common
• Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Types
• Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.BusinessLogic
• Microsoft.Dynamics.Common
• Microsoft.Dynamics.GP
```

to my project in Visual Studio,

Kindly suggest how I can do so.

Comment: Provided you have MS Dynamics installed and available, then simply add the references to your project. Then incorporate the classes using `using` statements.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add references to the libraries to your project.  Right click the project name and select "Add Reference" or if the project shows a references folder right click that and choose to add.  If the library doesn't show in the list then browse to where ever it is located and select it.

Then at the top of the file add a using command.  For example:
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Common;

Please feel free to post additional questions.

Comment: Hi, thankyou, but the thing is Dynamics is not visible in the list of references that come up in the window, none of them are there

Comment: Do you have MS Dynamics GP installed as part of your organization? If not, then you can't use it.

Comment: it would be installed on the server, but not on my current machine, any sugestion how i can still access them?

Answer (score 0):

Either Download and install the SDK on your machine, It will include the dlls needed to integrate with dynamics or copy the dlls from where ever you have them. (make sure you get the correct version for GP). From there you should create a folder in your project to hold the files in one place and copy them there. Once you have the library files you add references to the files by going to the browse sections of the reference manager and then browsing to the where you copied the files. (Quick note. make sure that you set copy local to true so that it will include the files locally when running and not look for them in the GAC). Once referenced you should be able to access the namespaces and include them with `using` keyword as needed.

Comment: I installed the SDK, but that only had the documentation, not the dlls

Comment: Check these two links. One is for [Visual Studio Tools for Microsoft Dynamics GP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc543538.aspx) the other [eConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973821.aspx). I've use eConnect before to create integration applications for GP

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are not getting the required dlls even after installing SDK, then add required Nugets online in visual studio(and later). After that you can start using the keyword "using" in your VS project.